# How to deserialize an array of JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have received the following `json` at my client application:

```
[{
    "ErrorCode" : 0,
    "ErrorMessage" : "The operation completed successfully."
}, {
    "configured" : true,
    "id" : "abc"
}]
```

Properties `ErrorCode` and `ErrorMessage` belong to the `ErrorInfo`-class and the properties `configured` and `id` belong to the `Data`-class.

I need to deserialize this JSON so that I can populate these two classes `ErrorInfo` and `Data`. How can I deserialize this json code to C#?

Comment: I'd use Json.NET... do you already have a class representing the objects? Do you want to access them dynamically? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Please edit the detail into the question - after reading the duplicate.

Comment: its not duplicate .. it is kind of array of jsons which belongs to different classes..

Comment: So how do you expect anything to know which class to deserialize which object as? It sounds like you should probably use LINQ to JSON instead.

Comment: i know .. the first json corresponds to ErrorInfo and second to Data. I am just trying a way out

Comment: Yes, *you* know that - but how are you expecting to communicate that to anything else? And how were *we* meant to know that from your original question? (And is it Session or Data? You're being inconsistent...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the NuGet packet Newtonsoft And use the class `JsonConvert`. An example:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);
```

Make also a class Movie whit the same properties and types.